# Angular 2 - Is routing allowed only in child component?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I'm having a main component as the root component

```
<tracker-module></tracker-module>
```

Under main component I have sub components like below:

```
   <header></header>
     <left-navigation></left-navigation>
     <my-app>
     </my-app>
    <footer></footer>
```

With the above structure, All the sub-components are rendering perfectly the way it should be(as these components does not have routing but just html).

But, I'm not getting to work out the page-content component as it contains the routing to different views (Only the main content of the page changes with the header, footer and left navigation remains the same). I'm not sure why? Any ideas on this would be of great help.

my boot.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {TrackerComponent} from './tracker.component';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
//enableProdMode();
bootstrap(TrackerComponent, []);
```

main.component.ts:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, Input, Output, SimpleChange, EventEmitter, ContentChild, ContentChildren, Renderer, IterableDiffers, Query, QueryList, TemplateRef} from 'angular2/core';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers}    from 'angular2/http';
import {CRUDService} from './service/CRUDService';
import {APIService} from './service/APIService';
/* Header, Footer, Left Navigation and my-app components*/
import {Header} from './Shared/layout/header/Header';
import {Footer} from './Shared/layout/footer/Footer';
import {LeftNavigation} from './Shared/layout/left-navigation/LeftNavigation';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
/* Header, Footer, Left Navigation and my-app components*/

@Component({
    selector: 'tracker-module',
    templateUrl: 'app/tracker.component.html',
    directives: [Header,Footer,LeftNavigation,AppComponent]
})
export class TrackerComponent {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

page.component.ts:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, Input, Output, SimpleChange, EventEmitter, ContentChild, ContentChildren, Renderer, IterableDiffers, Query, QueryList, TemplateRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,LocationStrategy,HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {TrackerUserAdmin} from "./Tracker/TrackerUserAdmin/TrackerUserAdmin";
import {CreateUserAdmin} from "./Tracker/CreateUserAdmin/CreateUser";
import {EditUserAdmin} from "./Tracker/EditUserAdmin/EditUser";
import {TrackerGroupAdmin} from "./Tracker/TrackerGroupAdmin/TrackerGroupAdmin";
import {CreateGroupAdmin} from "./Tracker/CreateGroupAdmin/CreateGroup";
import {EditGroupAdmin} from "./Tracker/EditGroupAdmin/EditGroup";
import {SavedSearch} from "./Tracker/SavedSearchAdmin/SavedSearch";
import {ResponseDateRules} from "./Tracker/ResponseDateRules/ResponseDateRules";
import {EditResponseDateRules} from "./Tracker/EditResponseDateRules/EditResponseDateRules";
import {CreateTicket} from "./Tracker/CreateTicket/CreateTicket";
import {TicketMaintenance} from "./Tracker/TicketMaintenance/TicketMaintenance";
import {TicketSearch} from "./Tracker/TicketSearch/TicketSearch";
/* Header and Footer*/
import {provideRouter, RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers}    from 'angular2/http';
import {CRUDService} from './service/CRUDService';
import {APIService} from './service/APIService';
/* Header and Footer*/

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/TrackerUserAdmin', name: 'TrackerUserAdmin', component: TrackerUserAdmin },
    { path: '/CreateUserAdmin', name: 'CreateUserAdmin', component: CreateUserAdmin },
    { path: '/EditUserAdmin', name: 'EditUserAdmin', component: EditUserAdmin },
    { path: '/TrackerGroupAdmin', name: 'TrackerGroupAdmin', component: TrackerGroupAdmin },
    { path: '/CreateGroupAdmin', name: 'CreateGroupAdmin', component: CreateGroupAdmin },
    { path: '/EditGroupAdmin', name: 'EditGroupAdmin', component: EditGroupAdmin },
    { path: '/SavedSearch', name: 'SavedSearch', component: SavedSearch },
    { path: '/ResponseDateRules', name: 'ResponseDateRules', component: ResponseDateRules },
    { path: '/EditResponseDateRules', name: 'EditResponseDateRules', component: EditResponseDateRules },
    { path: '/CreateTicket', name: 'CreateTicket', component: CreateTicket },
    { path: '/TicketMaintenance', name: 'TicketMaintenance', component: TicketMaintenance },
    { path: '/TicketSearch', name: 'TicketSearch', component: TicketSearch, useAsDefault: true }

])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        router.subscribe((val) => { /*whatever*/
            // alert("page verfication");
        });
    }
    //Do nothing
    ngOnInit() {
        alert("page verfication");
    }
}
```

However my alert inside my page.component.ts does work.

Comment: I don't know if my suggestion in my answer fully solves your issue but it's a first step. I can't see any `<router-outlet>` in the code you provided. To me it's not clear what the actual problem is. What's the exact step you are taking, what is the expected behavior, what is the actual behavior? Any error message in the browser console?

Comment: Gunter, router outlet will be in my page-component.html. I'm not getting any specific error message in my console. It's just that, I'm not getting the router working in my child component.

Comment: I just want to make sure you know that you are using a deprecated router. RC.3 contains a completely different router. Are you sure you want to spend time figuring out how it works in the old router?

Comment: If you have child routes the path of the parent routes need to end with `/...`. You would get an error for this. I'd suggest you create a Plunker that demonstrates what you try to accomplish (simplified code because I don't think you need 12 components and routes to discuss and understand the basic principle.

Comment: I've updated the question with ROUTE_PROVIDERS used in only one place.

Answer (score 1):

Don't provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` more than once. Either in `bootstrap(...)` or in `@Component()` of your root component, but nowhere else.

Comment: Gunter, does this mean if I have to use routes in my page-content component, I can use it once in my bootstrap like below?

bootstrap(TrackerComponent, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}) ]); 

still my page does not work with only one ROUTER_PROVIDERS :(

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below your question there is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I your main.component.ts your are using `<page-content></page-content>` but there is no any selector `<page-content></page-content>` but in your `app.component.ts` file selector is `'my-app'` and your are using `<page-content></page-content>`.Please change it to `'my-app'` that why is not showing any thing.

Comment: Mohammad, can you check the question again? I've modified the question for your understanding. The above is my actual HTML and previous HTML was to give a overall picture of my question. Sorry about that though.